# How do you calculate the gradient of nll_loss(log_softmax(A*A*X*W0*W1)) w.r.t A?

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus, python, subgradient

I would like to know how I can calculate the gradient of `null_loss(log_softmax(A*A*X*W0*W1))` w.r.t A.

All `A, X, W0, W1` are 2D matrices.
Even just showing how to calculate the gradient of `A*A*X*W0*W1` would also be helpful.

I'm trying to implement a function in pytorch so if you can show how you do it on pytorch, that would be awesome.

Thanks!

Comment: Someone can help you if you write your "null_loss" and "log_softmax" functions mathematically.

Comment: Ok, null_loss(log_softmax()) is same as cross_entropy and the description for cross_entropy can be found here https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html

Answer (score 0):

`null_loss(log_softmax())` is same as cross_entropy and the description for cross_entropy can be found here pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/…

But I'm still not sure how to get the gradient w.r.t A